# How to fix memory leaks for an autoreleased object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I have this method which leaks ~ 6KB :

```
+ (EInspectorFacilityInfo*) newWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
{
  if(node == nil) { return nil; }
  return (EInspectorFacilityInfo*)[[[EInspectorFacilityInfo alloc] initWithNode: node] autorelease];
}
```

here is a screenshot indicating the memory leak in instruments.
[image]

how can I get rid of this memory leak ?

Comment: rename your method. By convention methods that start with `new` return objects that are not autoreleased. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: Please show us how you are calling this method.

Comment: What about `EInspectorFacilityInfo` class? Maybe the leak could be inside it if you don't release the objects it manages. You don't need to cast.

Comment: by the way, this code is auto generated by SudzC

Comment: Check the dealloc() function whether missed to release some objects.

Comment: @Vanguarder  the class is auto-generated and the dealloc method is fine, it releases all retained objects.

Comment: Well, there is no problem with only this method other than the naming convention. You are probably leaking in some other place. That's why it is important that you pay more attention on how you have called this method, what you have done with the returned object. Unless you show us those codes we can't have any idea why you are leaking.

Comment: taskinoor is correct. Instruments is showing you where an object that has leaked was allocated, but that doesn't mean that's where it was leaked. Instruments can't determine that. In the list of leaks, you can find a specific leaked object and Instruments can show you the whole history of retains and releases on it. You have to look through those and see which bit of code failed to balance its retains with releases. Also, do a Build and Analyze and fix all identified issues.

Comment: @Matthias Bauch : thank you so much .. it has worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method has the word 'new' in it, so by the [Objective-C conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) it is expected to return an owning reference to the object, ie. an object with a retain count of 1. Auto releasing the object returns an object with a retain count of 0.

You must either remove the word new from the method name, or not auto release the object - in which case, the caller will be responsible for releasing it.

Comment: I replaced the word new with something like 'create', and the memory leak has gone off ... thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Small addition to Jasarien answer, you should name your method something like:

```
+ (EInspectorFacilityInfo*) inspectorFacilityInfoWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
```

This would fix your problem and match Cocoa coding style and spirit.